# Rails passing data from controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, charts

I have a Rails app with a model name `Product` that has attribute `price`

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
```

I want to draw a chart with `x-axis` is the product id and `y-axis` is the product price. I pass an array from the controller to the `app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee`. The array is 
`[[product1.id, product1.price],
  [product2.id, product2.price],
  [product3.id, product3.price]]`

I use `gon gem` to help me pass the data. Here is how I change the controller:

```
def index
 @products = Product.all
 gon.prices = []
 @products.each do |x|
   gon.prices.append([x.id, x.price])
 end
end
```

This `gon.prices` will be available in the `app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee`, thanks to `gon gem`.

My problem is that it seems not to be a good practice to create an array of array inside controller. My question is: Is there anyway I can pass the entire `@products` to javascript and extract the array inside the javascript instead of inside the controller? So I can do `gon.products = @products`

Comment: AJAX would be the best way to pass something from the server-side code to JavaScript. Something like jQuery would make this very easy to do.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in JavaScript, but it is going to require custom coding on your part.

As far as generating the array goes, why don't you do something like the following:

```
@products = Products.all
@array = @products.map { |p| [p.id, p.price] }
```

I personally do data passing to JavaScript by hand rather than relying on a gem like gon.  Cleaner that way.

In JavaScript, assuming that you're all set up for resources in JSON (so, you can visit `/products.json` and get JSON) and assuming that you're using jQuery, then your JavaScript could do the following:

```
// fetch the json file and parse
jQuery.getJSON('/products.json', function(data) {
  // convert the results into chart data
  var data_for_chart = jQuery.map(data.products, function(product) {
    return [product.id, product.price];
  });
  // do something with the data
});
```